# Run a task, enter username and password on an app automatically

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, windows-8.1, auto-form-fill

How can i make a program which will do following steps

1. Disconnect wifi
2. Open IDMan.exe
3. Fill the credentials such as userame, password and other boxes from a saved in notepad in that IDM dialog box
4. Press Ok
5. Reconnect the Wifi

Comment: Sounds like this could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - perhaps you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a [GUI Automation Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools)

1. Use a GUI Automation Tool
2. Record or build a script
3. Use Scheduler to schedule this to execute based on the triggers

***Pointers***

1. I am familiar with HP QTP/UFT which is a functional testing tool. and it's not a free tool, What you describe is very easy to do for somebody familiar with this tool
2. But it might be overkill if your goal is simply to achieve this as hobby and for home use. You might have to look for open source tools which can do the same.